# Pass cert password to Nginx with https site during restart

Tags: nginx, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, ansible

I configured nginx installation and configuration (together with setup SSL certificates for `https` site) via [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/). SSL certificates are under passphrases.

I want to write ansilbe task which is restarting nginx. The problem is the following.

Normally, nginx with https site inside asks for `PEM pass phrase` during restart. Ansible doesn't ask for that passphrase during execution of playbook.

There is [solution](http://red-badger.com/blog/2014/02/28/deploying-ssl-keys-securely-with-ansible/) with storing decrypted cert and key in some private directory. But I don't really want to leave my cert and key somewhere unencrypted.

How to pass password to nginx (or to openssl) during restart via `ansible`? Perfect scenario is following:

1. Ansible is asking for SSL password (via `vars_promt`). Another option is to use ansible vault.
2. Ansible is restarting nginx, and when nginx is asking for `PEM pass phrase`, ansible is passing password to nginx.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Nginx has [`ssl_password_file`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_password_file) parameter.

> Specifies a *file* with passphrases for secret keys where each passphrase is specified on a separate line. Passphrases are tried in turn when loading the key.

Example:

```
http {
    ssl_password_file /etc/keys/global.pass;
    ...
    server {
        server_name www1.example.com;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/keys/first.key;
    }
    server {
        server_name www2.example.com;
        # named pipe can also be used instead of a file
        ssl_password_file /etc/keys/fifo;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/keys/second.key;
    }
}
```

What you could do is keep that `ssl_password_file` in ansible-vault, copy it over, restart nginx and then if successful delete it.

I have no first-hand experience if it'll actually work or what other side-effects this might have(for example manual `service nginx restart` will probably fail), but it seems like a logical approach to me.

Comment: Copying it to disk might well defeat the whole point of not storing it on the server...

Comment: Or you can generate a certificate without pass phrase, by adding `-nodes` to openssl command while generating certificates

Comment: i think it is not a good choice because password file is very dangerous from a security point of view

Comment: Purpose of having password on key is to guard cert from being used when it leaks from storage (like S3). Ansible knows password from place like local ansible-vault and deploys cert/key combo only to webserver. This limits attack factor to only deployed web servers.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the permissions restrictive enough on the private key (e.g. only letting nginx be able to read it) this would probably be good enough.  Nginx will have to keep it loaded in memory anyway; this might be harder for an attacker to recover, but if they have root access to the box you should consider the key compromised regardless.

Alternatively, you can pipe the password in to the command that is restarting (e.g. `echo mypass | service nginx restart`).  This will cause it to be shown in plain text on process lists and shouldn't be considered any more secure.

I'd recommend locking down permissions on the file and not having a password on it.  I don't believe Ansible has any way to specify responses to individual prompts, other than sudo.