# Setting up ssl certification in nginx, error in password read

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having trouble setting up ssl for my nginx server. I was following this guide : [ssl guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tips-and-tricks-to-secure-your-nginx-web-server/). I'm on arch linux, I had to create the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and `/etc/nginx/sites-available` because I did not have them for some reason. My `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file contains the following :

```
 server {
        listen 192.168.0.26:443 ssl;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}
```

And my `nginx.conf` (only relevant part) :

```
http {
    include mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    .
    .
    .
```

I have my nginx.key and my nginx.crt in `/etc/nginx/ssl/`. I put a passphrase so nginx.key contains

```
---BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---
Proc-type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: ...

(here is the key)
---END RSA PRIVATE KEY---
```

in nginx.crt I only have the certificate not the Proc-type and dek-info part.

The error I get is the following :

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
[emerg] 497#497 cannot load certificate key "etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key": PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failed (SSL: error:2807106B:UI routines:UI_process:processing error:while reading strings error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password error:0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header: bad password read)
```

I'm really new to ssl and certificates so I don't know how to understand this error. Thanks for any help

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084347/pass-cert-password-to-nginx-with-https-site-during-restart) question/answer.